# Match words and ignore numbers with Regex

Tags: regex, apex

I have a list of words, for example, "at", "in", "on".
I need to match any of those exact words but I'm having some difficulty with one part of it.

Examples:

"I am **at** work" - should match with "at"

"I am **at**tracting honey bees" - should not match

"I am **at**123" - should match

I currently have something like this, but it's not doing exactly what i need.

`(?i)(\W|^)(at|in|on)(\W|$)`

Any assistance is appreciated

Comment: To match if not preceded or followed by a letter: [`(?i)(?<!\p{L})(?:at|[io]n)(?!\p{L})`](https://regex101.com/r/bwB7qP/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\W` means not a word character, and it seems you want to allow that on the left and right, except for a digit and without actually matching it.

If you want to match words delimited by word boundaries except for a digit, you can use lookaround assertions and match a non word character except for a digit using a negated character class `[^\W\d]`

```
(?<![^\W\d])(?:at|[io]n)(?![^\W\d])
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<![^\W\d])` Negative lookbehind, assert not a word character to the left except for a digit
- `(?:at|[io]n)` Match either `at` or `in` or `on`
- `(?![^\W\d])` Negative lookahead, assert not a word character to the right except for a digit

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vl3CuK/1).

If you don't want to allow a digit to the left and only to the right, you can us a word boundary on the left side of the pattern instead:

```
\b(?:at|[io]n)(?![^\W\d])
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C69CVx/1).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to match these words when surrounded by either whitespace, numbers, or the start/end of the string.  In that case, we can try using the following pattern:

```
(?:(?<!\S)|(?<!\D))(?:at|in|on)(?:(?!\S)|(?!\D))
```

This pattern says to:

- `(?:`

  - `(?<!\S)` lookbehind and assert whitespace or the start of the string precedes
  - `|` OR
  - `(?<!\D)` lookbehind and assert that a digit or the start of the string precedes
- `)`
- `(?:at|in|on)` match `at`, `in`, or `on`
- `(?:`

  - `(?!\S)` lookahead and assert whitespace or the start of the string follows
  - `|` OR
  - `(?!\D)` lookahead and assert that a digit or the start of the string precedes
- `)`

### Demo